# Serialize a List/Array as a comma sperated list in catel

Tags: catel

Next question to catel serialization. Is it possible to serialize a list/array of ints as a comma seperated list in xml. Now it looks like this:

```
<Ids>
  <arr:int>16</arr:int>
  <arr:int>27</arr:int>  
</Ids>
```

better

```
<Ids Values="16,27" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Customizing+serialization), you can customize anything with serializer modifiers:

```
public class MyObjectSerializerModifier : SerializerModifierBase<MyObject>
{
    public override void SerializeMember(ISerializationContext context, MemberValue memberValue)
    {
        if (string.Equals(memberValue.Name, "Ids"))
        {
            memberValue.Value = ConvertCollectionToCommaSeparatedValue(memberValue.Value);
        }
    }

    public override void DeserializeMember(ISerializationContext context, MemberValue memberValue)
    {
        if (string.Equals(memberValue.Name, "Ids"))
        {
            memberValue.Value = ConvertCommaSeparatedValuesToCollection(memberValue.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ok. I know the customize serializer. I thought maybe there is a flag to set. :-)